# Error 503 on asp.net sql server when visited by a large number of Concurrent Users

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching, http-status-code-503, windows-hosting

I have developed an images and video blogging website using `asp.net 4.0 & sql server 2008`. Everything was going well, but now I am facing Error 503 when a large number of users visit concurrently. My website is on a Shared Hosting (GoDaddy). 
What I have tried till now is:

1.using `using` Statements (i.e my connection disconnects after each query):

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constrg))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = Type;
                    if (prms != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SqlParameter p in prms)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adpt.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
```

2.`set NoCount` for sql procedures

But still I am facing the same problem. 
Now my questions are:

How can I get rid of this problem ?

Can it be solved by changing my hosting?

Is it something that I am missing in my code ?

Should i implement Caching? & How?

Comment: Shared hosting on Go-Daddy means no more than 25 users simultaneously! You should ask them what can be done. I experienced the same with 1&1 which is even worst (15 simultaneous connections).

Comment: changing the hosting is only option left ? or can i improve my code as well ?

Comment: Hundreds, Thousands or Millions users? Which are the performance of your website (cpu/memory).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx However, looks lil eyou have problems in connecting with the database not a problem on IIS.

Comment: yes, i too think that its problem with SQL, I have around 4k to 5k users concurrently hitting the same link i share.

Comment: You really need to get more detail on _why_. `503` isn't enough because all it really says is "unavailable" (not why). I don't know if you have access to your logs. If unsolved, you risk propagating it to whatever level of hosting. e.g. **if** SQL: `Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool..because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.` Hth.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have the access to the logs, i will try contacting godaddy for providing me the error logs, then will came here again.

Comment: @ShaminderSingh you need to configure error reporting anyway. How else are you going to find out about bugs? Maybe use ELMAH.

Comment: @usr i have successfully added elmah on my local machine, and is working fine. iam accessing it using /elmah.axd. But its not working online on Godaddy. i am getting an error 500. i have made some changes accordingly but in vain.

Comment: Why do you believe this is a database issue?  Are you getting database exceptions, or are queries running slowly?